# Ad hoc polymorphism in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm having trouble understanding how to create implementations of the following code:

```
Ad-hoc polymorphism
The third approach in Scala is to provide an implicit conversion or implicit
parameters for the trait.

scala> trait Plus[A] {
def plus(a1: A, a2: A): A
}
defined trait Plus

scala> def plus[A: Plus](a1: A, a2: A): A = implicitly[Plus[A]].plus(a1, a2)
plus: [A](a1: A, a2: A)(implicit evidence$1: Plus[A])A
```

How can I create a concrete implementation, e.g. to add strings, or integers?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
scala> implicit object StringPlus extends Plus[String] {
     | def plus(a1: String, a2: String) = a1+a2
     | }
defined module StringPlus

scala> plus("asd", "zxc")
res1: String = asdzxc
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example implementation of `Plus[Int]` would be something like:

```
scala> implicit val intPlus = new Plus[Int] { def plus(a1: Int, a2: Int):Int = a1 + a2 }
intPlus: Plus[Int] = $anon$1@42674853
```

... and you then use it:

```
scala> plus(1, 2)
res1: Int = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you allow me to change your syntax a bit, and change your operator (since `+` is already defined on e.g. `String`s):

```
trait Default[A] {

    def default(a: A): A

}

implicit def stringToDefault(s: String) = new Default[String] {

    def default(other: String) = ""

}

val s = "Hello"
val other = "Goodbye"

val res = s.default(other) // res = ""
```

Is this what you were looking for? Now we have successfully added a new method to the class `String` without modifying it, and if you change your type to for example a custom implementation of complex numbers, your `Plus` trait can be used.